# JAVA: Access values stored in an array of a constructor

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

how can I access the values of an int Array, that's initialised in the constructor of another class? 
I can access the object itself but what could I do if I want to check if it holds specific values?
Just started learning java, hope someone could help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Consider including example code, and remember to include what you have tried so far to access the data.

Comment: As @TheJim01 said, an example will make easier to answer your question. Welcome also to Java, here a code example that might help you to formulate a good question: https://ideone.com/kTKUVL

Answer (score 0):

You could store the array in an instance field of that class and then access it using a getter like this:

```
 public class AnotherClass {

    private int[] array;

    public AnotherClass() {
        array = new int[10];
    }

    public int[] getArray() {
       return array;
    }

}
```

Accessing items from the array would be done like this:

```
AnotherClass ac = new AnotherClass();
int firstItem = ac.getArray()[0];
```

If you want to prevent other parts of your program from modifying the contents of the array, you could pass the index to getter as a parameter instead of returning a reference to the actual array. In that case, you might want to provide a method, which would return the size of the array to be able to avoid possible ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exceptions when iterating over the array.

```
public class AnotherClass {

    private int[] array;

    public AnotherClass() {
        array = new int[10];
    }

    public int getItemFromArray(int index) {
       return array[index];
    }

    public int arraySize() {
       return array.length;
    }

}
```

In this case, accessing items from the array would look like this:

```
AnotherClass ac = new AnotherClass();
int firstItem = ac.getItemFromArray(0);
```